# Toolbar content visible over statusbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-nestedscrollview

i am using webview inside NestedScrollView which allows me to hide and show toolbar on scroll but there is an issue. the title from toolbar and hamburger is visible Image<[image: image showing title and part of hamburger]>

here is the main view code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/header_back_ground"
            android:max="100" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the code from app_bar_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.pressplus.android.demo.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/press_plus_demo" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have removed fitsystemwindow from the coordinatorlayout and its fixed.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```